# ListView entries are changing their layout when scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi I found a very strange problem that I can't understand.. hopefully someone can help me:

My list looks great if all views have place on the screen. As soon as the screen is smaller (or the list is longer) sometimes entries have different views than they should have. This problem can be constrained by scrolling up or down so that entries get out of the window.

I have a listview with different entry-types in it that have different layout files. This is the method that should decide what layout will be shown:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        NavigationListEntry i = entries.get(position);
        View v = view;
        if (v == null)
            switch(i.Type) {
            case ACTIVE_ENTRY:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nav_row_active, null);
                break;
            case HEADER:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nav_row_header, null);
                break;
            ...
            default:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nav_row_active, null);
                break;
            }
}
```

Do you have any ideas why this could occur?

/edit
It seems to work if I just remove "if (v == null)"

Comment: Hi, since you create different types of views: Have you overwritten the relevant methods (e.g. getViewTypeCount / getItemViewType etc...) in your adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `if(v==null)` you are not reusing the views which have already been inflated. If you do that the list view will be a bit sluggish.

The best way to do is

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    NavigationListEntry i = getItem(position);
    if(null == convertView){
        convertView = inflateNewView(i.type);
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else{
        //getting tag to obtain the already found views
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if(holder.type != i.type){
            convertView = inflateNewView(i.type); 
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
    }

    //always update the elements 
    holder.title.setText(i.getTitle());
    holder.desc.setText(i.getDesc());
    holder.content.setText(i.getContent());

    return convertView;
}

/**
 * Inflates a new view for the specified type
 * @return the newly inflated view
 */
private View inflateNewView(int type){
        View convertView = null;
        switch(type) {
        case ACTIVE_ENTRY:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nav_row_active, null);
            break;
        case HEADER:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nav_row_header, null);
            break;
        ...
        default:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nav_row_active, null);
            break;
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_RESOURCE, null);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
        holder.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
        holder.type = type;
        //setting tag to reduce hierarchy lookup
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    return convertView;
}
/**
 * Holder class to improve performance. Helps in reducing view hierarchy lookup
 */
private static class ViewHolder {

    TextView title;
    TextView desc;
    TextView content;
    int type;

}
```

This is the best way which will atleast attempt to recycle your views.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here, the recycled `View` you get in parameter might not be of the same `Type` you want to return. Let's say v is of type A, and its not null, the code you posted says nothing about that.

Comment: Okay but it should have the same position or not?

Comment: Also I found out that the Types are correct as well as the position

Comment: @KarstenDetmold Its hard to judge that from the piece of code you have posted, we don't know what you return in the end. Also in a situation like this, recycling can't be used.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the position will changing while scrolling or updating view.
Suggest using an array instead of position

Comment: why use an array, when scrolling position will change, the appropriate item for the particular position needs to be shown. That can be done using getView, why use an array for this